# Parallel eternal loop (does not exit loop)

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, supervisord, gnu-parallel

I'm currently using parallel to run a command in a defined amount of times as follow

```
   parallel -n0 -j2 "some command" ::: {1..999}
```

Where:

-n0 = don't use input (in this case, from 1 till 999)

-j2 = 2 parallel instances of "some command"

---

Problem:
After reach 999, parallel command do not exit as expected and "some command" is not called anymore under supervisor.

Is there a way to parallel exit naturally after finish loop?

---

*parallel --version
GNU parallel 20130922
Copyright (C) 2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013 Ole Tange and Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
GNU parallel comes with no warranty.
Web site: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel
When using GNU Parallel for a publication please cite:
O. Tange (2011): GNU Parallel - The Command-Line Power Tool, 
;login: The USENIX Magazine, February 2011:42-47.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Just included --timeout (is know issue on parallel)

https://superuser.com/questions/699432/gnu-parallel-hangs-as-one-process-is-sleeping

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
parallel -n0 -j2 echo ::: {1..999}
```

If yes: The problem is in `some command` and you need to give us more information.

Comment: Hi @Ole-Tange `parallel -n0 -j2 echo ::: {1..999}` works. (print white spaces in new lines). Same about `parallel -n0 -j2 "echo -e 'command'" ::: {1..999}` it does works.

Comment: Just decreased from 999 to 99 and is working as expected. Seems that parallel have some process management issue for that amount of inputs and does not send exit signal as expected.

Comment: If you can make a MCVE we may be able to fix it; but as you say: It works fine with `echo`, so I see it as related to `some command`. (GNU Parallel is not know to have any issues with running 999 jobs in parallel and is regularly tested with millions of jobs in total).